# How to make Action Button appear for certain opportunity stages?

Tags: lightning-experience, opportunity, lightning-apps, page-layout

I have a custom button called 'Revenue Forecast' in the 'Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions' in my Opportunity layout.

How do I make this button appear/diaasppear only in certain opportunity stages?

For instance how to make the button dissappear for 'closed' stage.

Please see screen shot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ask is not possible with Out of the box functionality in Salesforce as highlight panel derives the actions from the Page Layout. But still, I can think of one solution. Use record Types for Opportunity. One for Open opportunities and another for the closed one.As each record type associated with a page layout. Write a workflow to change the record type as soon as the user closes an opportunity and as result page layout will get changed. On open Opportunity page Layout, you can keep the action and remove the action from the Closed Opportunity Page Layout.

> Note:- As soon as you go for a new record type, It will involve extra
>   stuff like you may need to review your code, validation rules and
>   other things in your Org.